# Прототипное наследование в JS

Tags: javascript

Сначала я думал, что разобрался с прототипным наследованием в JS (ведь оно такое простое), а теперь мне кажется, что я не понимаю, зачем все это нужно.

Чаще всего наследование и создание подклассов нужно для того, чтобы использовать полиморфизм. Для этого используются ссылки или указатели на базовый класс, связанные с объектами производных классов. Это позволяет обрабатывать разные данные единообразно.

Но зачем в JS люди пихают в прототип методы, которые можно определить в самом классе? Ведь здесь нет полиморфизма. В чем профит? Как такое наследование в JS выглядит глобально, какие задачи решает, для чего оно?

Comment: Можно с примерами? Не очень понятно что значит "пихать метод в прототип" и "определять в самом классе"

Comment: @Alexey Ten, ну вот хотя бы вот это https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/vanillajs/js/model.js   Методы, специфичные для модели, запихали зачем-то в прототип. В классическом ООП в базовый класс выносятся общие методы. В данном же примере происходит какое-то странное колдунство вместо ООП

Comment: Ээээм, а ваше предложение?

Comment: И, в общем-то, `Model.prototype.method` это и есть метод объекта класса `Model`.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, "Ээээм, а ваше предложение?" Писать Model.method. Почему так не делают?

Comment: Потому что это будет то, что в других языках называется статический метод класса. Этого метода не будет у экземпляров.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, "Model.prototype.method это и есть метод объекта класса Model",если так, то как тогда будет выглядеть метод, расположенный в базовом классе?

Comment: А что вы называете базовым классом?

Comment: @Alexey Ten, класс, на основе которого создаются другие классы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77432/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-typemoon).

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, тут дело вот в чем. Помещение методов в прототип уменьшает требования к ресурсам. Если бы методы помещались в конструкторы самих дочерних объектов, то при каждом создании экземпляра такого объекта создавались бы и все его методы в памяти. Если таких объектов тысячи - налицо явный перерасход ресурсов. Таким образом, если метод является общим для всех потомков (реализует какую-то общую функциональность), имеет смысл вынести его в прототип.